# How do you calculate Vout on a voltage divider with a diode in parallel to R1?

Tags: diodes, voltage-divider

If you have a simple voltage divider circuit, but with a diode in parallel to R1, how would you calculate Vout? My attempt was a simple voltage divider (.5 * Vin) for Vin < 0.7, then Vout = Vin after 0.7 V. When I attempted this circuit in ltspice, it gave me a continuous function, contrary to my idea. How would this be calculated?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUvdTS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Your approach is correct but numeric results are wrong; because you don't take into account diode's on-resistance which is in parallel with R1. Note that the on-resistance changes a lot with forward current (Remember diode characteristics). Anyway, I made a simulation on Proteus which is a Spice-based simulator and it gave me that Vout = 0.5 x Vin for Vin < 1.4VDC.

Comment: The reason I didn't is because this is a simplified concept from a problem I have for homework using two zener diodes back to back in place of D1. We were only given Vz = 4.3v and Vdon = 0.7v

Comment: Spice gives you a continuous solution because is using the (exponential) continuous characteristic of the diode. Your approach, instead uses a piecewise model which is discontinuous (vertical I-V after passing the threshold). Introducing a constant diode resistance would still mean using a discontinuous model, this time with a slanted linear characteristic after threshold. So, it depends on the model you want to use for the diode. The general approach is to write enough KVL and KCL and characteristic equations to solve (numerically, if using nonlinear characteristic) for all unknown variables.

Comment: ...and that's how you use each and every character allowed in a comment. :-)

Comment: "Vout = Vin after 0.7 V" - what about the 0.7V drop across the diode?

Comment: Sean, what do you want? The divider ratio for (a) two extrem cases:>>0.7V and >>0.7V or (b) in dependency of a rising voltage? Because the diode is a non-linear element, you wil get, of course, a non-linear divider ratio. But it is not clear what your task is.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Here we go:

I've taken the equation for the diode current from Wikipedia, it's:

$$ I_D = I_S * (e^{\frac{U_D}{n*U_T}}-1) $$

\$U_D\$ is the diode voltage, \$U_T\$ is a temperature voltage, which is calculated from Temperature and Boltzmann constant. Or you can just approximate it with 25 mV at room temperature. \$I_S\$ is the saturation current and somewhere in the pico to nanoamp range. \$n\$ is the emission coefficient and, according to wikipedia, somewhere between 1 and 2. These are variables that aren't too important for the general form of the curve tho, so I'll just use values that seem somewhat reasonable.

.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fI9We6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Looking at the above circuit, we know that the current through \$R_2\$ is the combined current of \$R_1\$ and the diode. This can be written as:

$$ i_2 = \frac{u_1}{R_1} + I_s(e^{\frac{u_1}{n*U_T}}-1) $$

From Ohm's Law, we calculate \$u_2 = R_2 * i_2\$. Obviously, the rest of \$U_0\$ has to fall of over \$R_1\$, so:

$$u_1 = U_0-u_2 = U_0-R_2*i_2 = U_0 - R_2(\frac{u_1}{R_1} + I_s(e^{\frac{u_1}{n*U_T}}-1)) $$

which we can rewrite to:

$$ u_1 = \frac{U_0 - R_2*I_s(e^{\frac{u_1}{n*U_T}}-1)}{1+\frac{R_2}{R_1}} $$

As you can see, this equation has the usual voltage divider part in it (\$u_1 = \frac{U_0}{1+R_2/R_1}\$) but also an "error voltage", introduced by the diode that rises exponentially with \$u_1\$ itself. You can also see that \$R_2\$ is factored in with the error voltage.

Since we cannot rewrite this equation in its explicit form, we just put it into Matlab and solve numerically for a sweep over \$U_0\$. My matlab code is the following:

```
function [ u0, u1 ] = sweep_diode_divider( U0_sweepstart, U0_sweepend, n_sweep, R1_, R2_, Is_, Ut_, n_ )
    syms U0_ R1 R2 Is Ut n U1_ Uc;
    U1_(U0_, R1,R2,Is,Ut,n) = (U0_ - Is*R2*(exp(Uc/(Ut*n)) - 1))/(R2/R1 + 1);

    u0 = linspace(U0_sweepstart, U0_sweepend, n_sweep);
    u1 = [];
    res = 0;
    for u = u0
        res = vpasolve(Uc == U1_(u, R1_, R2_, Is_, Ut_, n_), Uc, res);

        u1 = [u1 double(res)];
    end
end
```

We can now plot this for plausible values of \$I_s, U_T, n\$ and \$R1=R2=1000\$ and \$0V < U_0 < 10V\$ (calculation takes about 20sec for 100 points):

```
>> [u0, u1] = sweep_diode_divider(0, 10, 100, 1000, 1000, 1e-9, 25e-3, 1.75);
>> plot(u0, u1)
```

[image]

This is the kind of curve you would expect and that LTSpice also gives me.